# Create inferior triangular matrix without extra vertical lines

Tags: tables

I want to create an inferior triangular matrix like shown in the picture below.

[image: Desired result.]

My attempt was the following:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \cline{1-3}
  B & X &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{1-3}
  C & X & X &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{1-4}
  D & X & X & X & X &   &   \\ \cline{1-5}
  E & X & X & X & X &   &   \\ \cline{1-6}
  F & X & X & X & X & X &   \\ \cline{1-7}
  G & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \cline{1-7}
    & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But, as seen below, it does not produce the desired result.

[image: Result so far.]

The problem is with the vertical lines. Does anybody know how to make vertical lines in a table that span only for some desired lines? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked,

> Does anybody know how to make vertical lines in a table that span only for some desired lines?

The answer is surprisingly simple: Don't generate any empty cells in the upper-right part of the array. Put differently, omit the `&` empty-cell generators.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
                               \cline{1-2}
  B & X                     \\ \cline{1-3}
  C & X & X                 \\ \cline{1-4}
  D & X & X & X             \\ \cline{1-5}
  E & X & X & X & X         \\ \cline{1-6}
  F & X & X & X & X & X     \\ \hline
  G & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
    & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would this method work for superior triangular matrices as well?

Comment: @Jeff - It wouldn't. You'd have to use something like `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` for a row with 1 empty cell at the far left, `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}` for a row in which the first 2 cells are empty, etc. I'd like to suggest, though, that you start writing upper-diagonal and lower-diagonal matrices without *any* horizontal or vertical rows. I think you'll like the resulting look a lot.

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

The environment `{NiceTabular}` is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but adds some functionalities. In particular, there is a key `hvines` which draws all the rules. With the key `corners`, it's possible to specify some corners (such as `NE` for *north-east*): the corners are computed by taking into account the empty cells and the rules are not drawn in the corners.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[hvlines, corners = NE] % NE = north east
  B & X &   &   &   &   &   \\ 
  C & X & X &   &   &   &   \\ 
  D & X & X & X & X &   &   \\ 
  E & X & X & X & X &   &   \\ 
  F & X & X & X & X & X &   \\ 
  G & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ 
    & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]